# Variable substitution in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

can you please help me with "define" namespace in hive(2.2.0)? Below is what am I doing :

```
$ hive -d foo=eg_test;
hive>set foo;
foo=eg_test
hive>select * from ${foo};
OK
Time taken: 5.13 seconds
hive> set hivevar:foo;
hivevar:foo=eg_test
```

It seems that "define" namespace by default initializes the variable at "hivevar" namespace (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

Now I'm doing :

```
hive>set define:x=5;
hive>set x;
x is undefined
hive>set define:x
define:x=5
hive> set hiveconf:x;
hiveconf:x is undefined as a hive configuration variable
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: null
hive> set hivevar:x;
hivevar:x is undefined as a hive variable
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: null
```

My question is, where this x variable has been initialized? in which namespace?How can I retrieve it using ${ } as ${define:x} results in exception.

Comment: Hive CLI is deprecated in favor of beeline, by the way